# How do I log into Windows by typing the last character of my PIN?

Tags: windows-10, login-screen

At home, after I finish typing in the last character of my four-digit PIN, Windows automatically logs in and shows me my desktop.

On my desktop PC at work, however, typing in the last character of my five-character (four digits and a special character) Windows does nothing until I hit the enter key.

Both machines are running Windows 10 build 1803 with the latest updates installed. The user accounts are both (different) Microsoft accounts.

What is causing this behavior on the work pc? Is it the inclusion of the special character in the PIN?

How can I make it so that entering the last character of the PIN is enough to trigger login, removing the need to hit enter?

**Edit:** Please make note that the work PC *isn't really all that different from my home PC.* I am my own administrator and employees are responsible for their machines, we don't do custom policies or anything like that. I would ask local IT support but the thing is, I **am** local IT support.

Comment: First of all, welcome to Super User!  We are always glad to help, but forgive me for asking the obvious question:  did you consult your IT support staff at work to see if they already have the answer?

Comment: Are you actually entering a PIN at work, or a password? Policies can be applied to computers in a business environment requiring them to behave in certain ways. While a PIN generally is accepted as soon as it is complete, it is likely that policies can require pressing Enter afterwards. In the case of a password, pressing Enter is ALWAYS required to signify that the password is complete and should be checked and processed for authentication. You should definitely check with your local IT in either case. They will be able to either make this work the way you want, or give you reasons why not.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because whether this is a PIN v Password issue or not, local IT are the ones who will be able either to resolve the issue, or provide reasons why not.

Comment: @Run5k I am part of IT support at my job.

Comment: @music2myear I am 100% certain that I am entering a PIN at work, it's just the regular one Windows lets you set. We don't have any policies set regarding our passwords. There aren't really any specific organization settings set either, the only policy I adjusted so far is Windows update.

Comment: @MátéJuhász Again I am entering a PIN. Windows 8 and up allow users to set a PIN to make logging in easier.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that you are IT. I have retracted my close vote, and welcome. Another way to tell PIN v PWD is that the login usually says "Enter your PIN" or something similar. Also, this is not an uncommon question: https://www.google.com/search?q=have+to+press+enter+after+entering+pin+windows+10 with some noting its a bug, and others noting this may have been added in later builds of Windows 10. What build do you have?

Comment: @music2myear Version 1803, build 17134.191 on both machines. I'm certain that I am entering PINs.

Comment: You have probably found a problem in Windows. You can only signal it to Microsoft, but keep on using Enter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The minimum length is four digits (0–9 only; no letters or special characters allowed). When we set the PIN as four digits, to sign in to Windows on our laptop, type the PIN, we don’t even need to press the Enter key — just type the numbers.

[How to Add a PIN to Your Account in Windows 10](https://www.howtogeek.com/232557/how-to-add-a-pin-to-your-account-in-windows-10/)

For your question:
How can I make it so that entering the last character of the PIN is enough to trigger login, removing the need to hit enter?

We can refer the articles: [How to log in using PIN without pressing ENTER?](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-hello-winpc/how-to-log-in-using-pin-without-pressing-enter/bf075def-e659-4895-b6d9-2d47456cc458)

By default, the PIN is four digits, we don’t need to press the Enter key, in the article, the user need to hit enter, but when he changed the PIN and it does not need ENTER. we can test using PIN without pressing ENTER according to the article.

1. The length of the PIN is more than four but all numbers.
2. The length of the PIN is more than four digits but includes numbers and other characters.

If we need to hit Enter in both cases, I think because the system defines the length of the PIN to be four digits, or customize its length. So if the system recognizes that the length of the PIN is only a minimum of 4 digits, he recognizes that the four digits are entered directly after being typed. When the PIN length exceeds four digits, he cannot recognize the length of the PIN until all PIN characters are entered, so we need to press the Enter key.

We can also configure PIN Complexity via Group Policy

[How to enable & configure PIN Complexity Group Policy in Windows 10](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/pin-complexity-group-policy-windows-10)